# R - is.element inside sapply for column with comma seperated values

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column named Disease and a list Disease_List(unique values of Disease column)like this

```
Disease
--------------------------
Diabetes, Blood Pressure
Diabetes
Anemia
No
Blood Pressure,Anemia
```

I tried using sapply function as below:

```
xx<-sapply(my_data$Disease, function(x) is.element(toString(stri_split_fixed(x,","))[[1]],unlist(Disease_List))[[1]]  + 0)
```

output

```
> xx
  0 1 1 0 0
```

It is considering the comma separated values as a new value which is not in the list and returns 0.

I need the output like this

```
Diabetes    Blood Pressure    Anemia    
1            1                 0
1            0                 0
0            0                 1
0            0                 0
0            1                 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df, mtabulate(strsplit(df$Disease, ",\\s*")))
#                    Disease Anemia Blood Pressure Diabetes No
#1 Diabetes, Blood Pressure      0              1        1  0
#2                 Diabetes      0              0        1  0
#3                   Anemia      1              0        0  0
#4                       No      0              0        0  1
#5    Blood Pressure,Anemia      1              1        0  0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Disease = c("Diabetes, Blood Pressure", "Diabetes", 
 "Anemia", "No", "Blood Pressure,Anemia")), row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 cbind(my_data,+Vectorize(grepl)(disease_list,my_data['Disease']))
                   Disease Diabetes Blood Pressure Anemia No
1 Diabetes, Blood Pressure        1              1      0  0
2                 Diabetes        1              0      0  0
3                   Anemia        0              0      1  0
4                       No        0              0      0  1
5    Blood Pressure,Anemia        0              1      1  0
```

You can also use 
`+sapply(disease_list,grepl,my_data$Disease)`

where

```
my_data = read.table(col.names = 'Disease',
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     strip.white = TRUE
                     sep = '|',
                     text = ' Diabetes, Blood Pressure
                                            Diabetes
                                               Anemia
                                                   No
                                Blood Pressure,Anemia')
 disease_list = unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(as.character(my_data$Disease),','))))
```

Comment: I think there is two Blood Pressure in your out put

Comment: Other than that pretty neat solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Method from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit_e(df, "Disease", sep = ",",mode = "binary", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = F)
                   Disease Disease_Anemia Disease_Blood Pressure Disease_Diabetes Disease_No
1 Diabetes, Blood Pressure              0                      1                1          0
2                 Diabetes              0                      0                1          0
3                   Anemia              1                      0                0          0
4                       No              0                      0                0          1
5    Blood Pressure,Anemia              1                      1                0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` option using `tidyr::separate_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    separate_rows(Disease, sep = ",\\s*") %>%
    mutate(n = 1) %>%
    spread(Disease, n, fill = 0) %>%
    select(-row)
#  Anemia Blood Pressure Diabetes No
#1      0              1        1  0
#2      0              0        1  0
#3      1              0        0  0
#4      0              0        0  1
#5      1              1        0  0
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Disease
'Diabetes, Blood Pressure'
Diabetes
Anemia
No
'Blood Pressure,Anemia'", header = T)
```

Comment: There's a small problem here.  The "Blood" and "Pressure" are treated as different columns.

Comment: @wibeasley Ah you're right. I fixed it by specifying `sep` in `separate_rows`. This now also correctly deals with comma-separated terms with/without an additional white-space after the comma.

Comment: I like how you slipped in the `\\s*` in the `sep` argument.  I was thinking that the extra space would require `stringr::str_trim()` or `gsub("^\\s*(.+)\\s*$", "\\1", Disease)`

Comment: @wibeasley (One of the) nice things about `separate_rows` is that it calls `stringi::stringi_split_regex` to do the splitting so we can use more complex regular expressions inside `sep`.